# How is Slim container accessible within the route method

Tags: php, scope, slim

I'm starting to build my own framework. Currently, I'm doing a research about MVC design pattern and I've looked thru Laravel and CodeIgniter. Until I saw Slim and its documentation. I got stock on this part because I don't understand how it works:

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['myService'] = function() {
    // return instance of myService
};

$app->get('/foo', function ($req, $res, $args) {
    $myService = $this->myService; // how did Slim do this?
    return $res;
});
```

With this way of getting the container, how is "myService" accessible in route method when the container should be out of variable scope? I can't find it in Slim App class.

Comment: They might be using the Closures [bindTo()](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php)-method. With that, you can set which context the Closure should have (what `$this` should refer to).

Comment: Quoting from [Slim docs](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html): *If you use a Closure instance as the route callback, the closure’s state is bound to the Container instance.* It is done [the way the previous comment suggests](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/App.php#L237).

Comment: I see. I've read the php documentation about closures. But how about the `$container` from `$container = $app->getContainer();`? From my understanding, it is a copy of `private $container` from App class. How come the elements of `$container` is visible in route function?

Comment: I get it now. `$container` is an instance and not a copy. Thanks for helping! I appreciate it.